# .htaccess rewrite for date like YYYY-MM-DD

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to write a rule for a date (YYYY-MM-DD)

```
domain.com/2017-11-17
```

I did some research here and I came up with this:

```
RewriteRule ^image-day/([0-9]{4}+-[0-9]{2}+-[0-9]{2})/?$ admin.php?do=image_day&date=$1 [L]
```

It seems to work, but I was wondering if there is a better or more robust way to do it.

Can i improve on my rule?

Comment: Its not much prettier but you could convert [0-9] to \d

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteRule ^(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})/?$ admin.php?do=image_day&date=$1 [L]
```

And in this case, you can put the date at the root, as in your question.